# Conditionally set FastAPI response model for route

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to return a list of objects of type Company, including only "approved" ones, and with more or less attributes depending on whether the user requesting the list is a superuser or a regular user. This is my code so far:

```
@router.get("/", response_model=List[schema.CompanyRegularUsers])
def get_companies(db: Session = Depends(get_db), is_superuser: bool = Depends(check_is_superuser)):
    """
    If SU, also include sensitive data.
    """
    if is_superuser:
        return crud.get_companies_admin(db=db)
    return crud.get_companies_user(db=db)
#
```

The function correctly returns the objects according to request (ie., only `is_approved=True` companies if a regular request, and both `is_approved=True` and `is_approved=False` if requested by a superuser. Problem is, both cases use `schema.CompanyRegularUsers`, and I'd like to use `schema.CompanySuperusers` when SU's make the request.

How can I achieve that feature? I.e, is there a way to conditionally set the `response_model` property of the decorator function?

I've tried using `JSONResponse` and calling Pydantic's `schema.CompanySuperusers.from_orm()`, but it won't work with a list of Companies...

Comment: BTW it is better to return dict with list in key "items" for example, than just list. It is simpler to add some meta information, for example pagination

Comment: Thanks @Arthur Shiriev, that totally makes sense. Thing is, FastAPI's default response is a list. Do you know the "correct way" to return a dict, with the list (among other meta information)?

Comment: something like this https://gist.github.com/lesnik512/fbc802c431aea6428c0a85bc2f44fe7d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up solving the riddle by returning a custom JSONResponse. It doesn't show up in the automatic documentation, but I think I can tackle that down the road. Code is as follows, in case it helps someone else:

```
...
from pydantic import parse_obj_as
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
...

@router.get("/", response_model=List[schema.CompanyRegularUsers])
def get_companies(db: Session = Depends(get_db), is_superuser: bool = Depends(check_is_superuser)):
    """
    If SU, also include sensitive data.
    """
    if is_superuser:
        companies = parse_obj_as(List[schema.CompanyAdmin], crud.get_companies_admin(db=db))
        return JSONResponse(jsonable_encoder(companies))
    return crud.get_companies_user(db=db)
```

So, in the `is_admin` branch, the path operation calls pydantic's `parse_obj_as` in order to map the list of objects returned by SQLAlchemy's query as a list of `CompanyAdmin` objects. Then, it uses `jsonable_encoder`, the encoder FastAPI uses under the hood for every default response, to serialize the list.

Edit: Typo

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use `Union` type operator.

Your code would become

```
from typing import Union

@router.get("/", response_model=List[Union[schema.CompanyRegularUsers, schema.CompanySuperUser]])
```

this way, you specify as response model a list of either `schema.CompanyRegularUsers` or `schema.CompanySuperUser`

Let me know if it works, since I didn't test it

Comment: Thanks Isabi. But as far as I can tell, this will allow for either schema to be used, but still needs a way to actually controlling which of the two will be used for the response...

Comment: You have to control which one to return. Either you patch a function that does that for you, or you do that in the route function. Response models of the decorator are not dynamic, so you'll have to return the union of both models since you only know at runtime which one will be returned

Comment: @Isabi: But how would that function work? That's what I'm after, and my problem is both `get_companies_admin`  and `get_companies_user` return a `Company` SQLAlchemy model (ie., with full attributes, including those I want to hide from regular users), which the `response_model=schema.CompanyRegularUsers` filters out for me. I think that filtering should occur on the `get_companies_user` function, but how could I accomplish that? Thanks for your time!

Comment: It works the same way you posted it ```if is_superuser:
        return crud.get_companies_admin(db=db)
    return crud.get_companies_user(db=db)```
Not sure about `sqlalchemy` how can work with pydantic, but this sketches the idea

Comment: @Isabi, that won't do because both functions return the same SQLAlchemy model. Filtering should occur during response. I ended up solving it as detailed in the accepted answer. Thank you for your time!